# Editar dados de um combo box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Estou tendo um problema em minha aplicação em asp.net mvc. O que ta acontecendo que é que, na hora de salvar os dados, meus combo boxes carregam dados de enums. Esses combo boxes são de uma aplicação para uma escola, onde neles são carregados a série/ano, a turma e o turno. Mas o problema que eu to tendo é que, na hora que eu vou editar esses dados que foram salvos, esses combo boxes retornam ao valor padrão, ou seja, os dados que já vem carregados. Minha dúvida é: como que eu faço pra que ao tentar alterar esses dados, eles carreguem os dados que já foram salvos, pois todos os outros dados carregam normalmente, só os dos combos boxes que tem isso, e detalhe, se por acaso eu não arrumar os dados do jeito que estava antes na hora de editar, os dados dos combos são alterados para os valores default.

Vou postar o código deles aqui:

Ano/Série

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ano, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select name="Ano">
                        @for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
                        {
                            <option>@i</option>
                            <p>º</p>
                        }
                    </select>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ano)
                </div>
            </div>
```

Turma

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Turma, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select name="Turma">
                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Turmas)
                        {
                            <option>@item</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Turma)
                </div>
            </div>
```

Turno

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Turno, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select name="Turno">
                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Turno)
                        {
                            <option>@item</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Turno)
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode carregar essas informações de outras formas deixando o framework trabalhar para você. Utilize [SelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) para tal funcionalidade.

***Explicação***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse [SelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) temos que informar:

- ***items***: uma lista de valores
- ***dataValueField***: um valor que identifique o select internamente o mesmo que `<option value="dataValueField">` sendo o mesmo o value.
- ***dataTextField***: um valor que simbolize a descrição que fica entre os `<option>dataTextField</option>`.
- ***selectedValue***: informação utilizado quando deseja posicionar o select em determinado item, geralmente utilizado em alterações de registro e fica como tag dentro do option `selected="selected"` assim: `<option selected="selected"></otpion>`

**Exemplo:**

***No Controller***

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Dictionary<int, int> Anos = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++){
        Anos.Add(i, i);
    }
    ViewBag.DropAno = new SelectList(Anos.AsEnumerable(), "key", "value", 5);
    return View();
}
```

***Na View desse Controller***

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropAno")
```

***Automáticamente ele vai carregar esse select para você como mostrado na figura abaixo***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Código html gerado:***

```
<select id="DropAno" name="DropAno">
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

---

**Outro exemplo com uma lista de alguma class**

*Dentro do Metodo do Controller*

```
List<Pessoa> pessoas = new List<Pessoa>();
pessoas.Add(new Pessoa(1, "Nome 1"));
pessoas.Add(new Pessoa(2, "Nome 2"));
pessoas.Add(new Pessoa(3, "Nome 3"));
ViewBag.DropPessoas = new SelectList(pessoas.AsEnumerable(), "Id", "Nome");
```

*View daquele metodo do controller*

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropPessoas")
```

*Carregar esse SelectList posicionado no item da alteração*

```
List<Pessoa> pessoas = new List<Pessoa>();
pessoas.Add(new Pessoa(1, "Nome 1"));
pessoas.Add(new Pessoa(2, "Nome 2"));
pessoas.Add(new Pessoa(3, "Nome 3"));
int Numero = 3; // automaticamente ele vai carregar e posicionar o select no numero 3
ViewBag.DropPessoas = new SelectList(pessoas.AsEnumerable(), "Id", "Nome", Numero);
```

Nesse último exemplo de código percebe que foi passado mais um item o `Numero` sendo esse o item que veio como padrão da sua base de dados para alterar, ou seja, ele vai carregar a select e posicionar.

***Referências***

- [SelectList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)
- [ASP.Net MVC SelectList, SelectedValue, and DropDownListFor](http://peternewhook.com/2013/02/asp-net-mvc-selectlist-selectedvalue-dropdownlistfor/)

Comment: No controller que foi citado ai, seria o edit e o create ? Ou pode colocar no index mesmo ? Ou só no edit, onde estou tendo problemas ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago coloque no método do controller que vai carregar a sua view. Exemplo: se sua view é o edit coloque no metodo edit

Comment: Exato, to tendo problema só nele. Ele não carrega os dados que foram cadastrados. Ele sempre carrega os dados default. Mas se eu colocar esse método ai no edit, vou precisar colocar dessa maneira no create também ? Não né ?

Comment: Você vai precisar colocar a todo momento que for utilizar, se no seu create tem esse item então tem que utilizar também!

Comment: Aah, entendi ! Então tenho que muda meu controller edit e create. Só uma outra dúvida, essa parte aqui: "Dictionary<int, int> Anos = new Dictionary<int, int>();", Dictionary seria o meu enum certo ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago pode ser eu não sei como ta sua aplicação porque você só colocou a sua view, mas, a lógica é essa pode utilizar

Comment: Quer que eu coloque as partes do controller que tem o edit e o create pra ficar mais fácil ? Se quiser coloco os enums que to usando também ! O ano é o único que uso sem enum !

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14268/discussion-between-fccdias-and-erik-thiago)